# How to debug windows storage applications

Tags: windows-10, uwp

I was using Properties.Settings.Default to store persistent data between sessions. For example, I was using Properties.Settings.Default.mute to store a boolean of whether or not to mute sounds.

I went online and it recommends to use Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.Current.LocalSettings.Values. So I try setting Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.Current.LocalSettings.Values["mute"] and using that, but that actually crashes the debugger, so I can't even debug whatever the issue is.

Comment: Where in your application are you trying to read the value? Did you check to see if the returned value were null?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to set some data in **Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.Current.LocalSettings.Values["mute"]** before use it,  for example:

```
Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.Current.LocalSettings.Values["mute"]  = true;
```

(or false or an other value  ) the you can get it like this

```
var t = Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.Current.LocalSettings.Values["mute"];
```